# Laravel Eloquent: Reduce number of queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have 250 users in `users` table and each user has one or many books, and each book has one or many chapters. Now I would like to print the user names, with their book names.

Controller:

```
$users = User::all();
```

in blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
      <td>
        @foreach($user->books as $book)
          {{ $book->name }},
          @endforeach
      </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach

# of queries 252
```

Now to overcome the n+1 problem, the query should be

```
$users = User::with('books')->get();
```

Now the # of queries are only 2.

I want to print the book names with number of chapters like this-> 
BookName(# of chapters). So in my blade

```
@foreach($users as $user)
      <tr>
          <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
          <td>
            @foreach($user->books as $book)
              {{ $book->name }} ({{ $book->chapters->count() }}),
              @endforeach
          </td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
```

so for 750 books with 1500 chapters the # of queries are about 752 and it increases if chapter number increases.

Is there any better Eloquent way to reduce it or should I go for raw SQL queries?

Comment: `with` supports nested relationships. You should be able to use `with('books.chapters')`

Comment: wow.. thanks.. it works.. can you provide any documentation to read?

Comment: u can add this as an answer. i will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the Eloquent Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> **Nested Eager Loading**
>
> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For example, let's eager load all of the book's authors and all of the author's personal contacts in one Eloquent statement:
>
> `$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();`

In your case, you can retrieve the nested relationships you need with the following:

```
User::with('books.chapters')->get();
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to load all chapters data and then manually count each collection. Use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) instead:

```
$users = User::with('books')->withCount('chapters')->get();
```

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models.

Comment: This is likely a more efficient answer, as each chapter object is not being loaded into memory. Upvoted.

Comment: yes. thanks to alexey mezenin also. I learned two new things. voted up

Comment: Though I understood the point, but there is no direct relationship of users and chapters. the relationship in models are-> user hasMany books, book belongs to user and book hasMany chpaters. Chapter belongs to book. So the line `User::with('books')->withCount('chapters')->get();` returns `bad method call exception Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::chapters()`; any idea about how to define this user to chapter relationship?

Comment: In this case you can create `hasManyThrough` relationship or add `withCount()` to the `books` relation (or better create separate relationship for this like `booksWithChaptersCounted`).

Comment: You pass a closure to `with('books')` so it looks liek `with(['books' => function($query) {...}])`  and then within that closure you add `$query->withCount('chapters');` This should return your desired chapter count on each book that belongs to a user. Using a hasManyThrough will give you a global count of the chapters adding ALL the books that belong to the user. I understand that, if you want a global count, that's the way to go, if you want a per-book count, you'd use this closure to execute `withCount()` on the books query to add the chapter count to each book.